# Sencha Touch 2 - Carousel Stuck on First Panel Only After Build

Tags: android, ios, extjs, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I have a carousel in a panel which displays and works fine before I build the app through the sencha sdk.  After I've built it, however, the carousel still displays properly but no longer allows me to swipe between the items.

```
Ext.define('SycsApp.view.HotOffers', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.carousel.Carousel', 'Ext.TitleBar'],

    config: {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    ui: 'top-sub',
                    title: 'Hot Offers',
                },
                {
                    id: 'hotOffersCarousel',
                    xtype: 'carousel',
                    width: '100%',
                    items: [
                        {
                            html : 'Item 1',
                            style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
                        },
                        {
                            html : 'Item 2',
                            style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                        },
                        {
                            html : 'Item 3'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }
});
```

The reason the layout is set to card is that this view is part of an encompassing tab panel.    I'm not getting any error messages from the console when I run the app after the build, either.

Any help with why this would possibly be happening would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the way it was being added to the main card view.

```
Ext.define('SycsApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'mainView',
requires:  ['SycsApp.view.HotOffers'],

config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    id: 'MainView',
    ui: 'bottom',
    layout: 'card',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Hot Offers',
            layout: 'fit',
            iconCls: 'hotoffer',
            //items: [Ext.create('SycsApp.view.HotOffers')], // carousel doesn't work after build
            items:  [{xtype: 'hotOffersView'}] // carousel works after build
        },
        {
            title: 'All Savings',
            layout: 'fit',
            iconCls: 'list',
            items:  [{xtype: 'allSavingsMainView'}]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

The `xtype: 'hotOffersView'` must be added to the Hot Offers view:

```
Ext.define('SycsApp.view.HotOffers', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'hotOffersView',
    requires: ['Ext.carousel.Carousel', 'Ext.TitleBar'],

    config: {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    ui: 'top-sub',
                    title: 'Hot Offers',
                },
                {
                    id: 'hotOffersCarousel',
                    xtype: 'carousel',
                    width: '100%',
                    items: [
                        {
                            html : 'Item 1',
                            style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
                        },
                        {
                            html : 'Item 2',
                            style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                        },
                        {
                            html : 'Item 3'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }
});
```